# date value mismatch while inserting values from csv to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, csv

In python I am getting date value mismatch error while inserting values from csv to mysql

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    print(row)      
    sql = "INSERT INTO `test1` (Date,High_Temp,Low_Temp,Humidity,Wind) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.executemany(sql,[(datetime.strptime(row['Date'],'%y/%m/%d').strftime('%y/%m/%d'),row['High_Temp'],row['Low_Temp'],row['Humidity'],row['Wind'])])
    conn.escape_string(sql)
    conn.commit()
```

Error I see:

> ValueError: time data '01-01-11' does not match format '%y/%m/%d' This is the error i getting – sarika 55 mins ago

Date Column(in csv):

```
 01-01-11
 02-01-11
 03-01-11
 04-01-11
...
```

Comment: ValueError: time data '01-01-11' does not match format '%y/%m/%d'  This is the error i getting

Comment: Date
01-01-11
02-01-11
03-01-11
04-01-11
05-01-11
06-01-11
07-01-11
08-01-11
09-01-11
10-01-11
11-01-11
12-01-11
13-01-11 this is my csv Date column

Answer (score 0):

Your dates in your `csv` are `01-01-11` you are using `'%y/%m/%d'` there are no `/` in your format use `'%y-%m-%d'` with `hyphens`